# Is there an simple way or a function that can get the difference, product or quotient of all numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

So I just want to know if there's a simpler way to get all the numbers in an array and subtract, add, multiply, and divide them better than what I have done here: (the code here is to subtract all the numbers in an array)

```
 double diff = numArray[0];
 for (int i=1; i!=numArray.length; i++) {
    diff -= numArray[i];
 }
```

or is there a function that can make my life easier, because I know there is a function to add all the numbers in an array but wasn't able to find anything else.

Comment: Use a `DoubleStream`? I assume `numArray` is a `double[]`. Then your difference, product or quotient can be calculated in a `reduce`.

Comment: That's pretty simple already. If you're looking for something to make your life easier, code may not be the answer.

Comment: Sum and product can be done with one-line stream methods, since those are common operations, but I don’t think it’s common to get the “difference of a list” or the “quotient of a list.”  Your current implementation is the best anyone can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaner? Your code is pretty clean I think.

However, an alternative may be using streams:

```
double[] numArray = { 17.0, 13.0, 36.5, 7.5, 3.2 };
double result = DoubleStream.of(numArray)
    .skip(1)
    .reduce(numArray[0], (a, b) -> a - b);
System.out.println(result);
```

What happens here? We use the Stream specialization for primitive `double`s, `DoubleStream`, in order to walk over the elements of the `double` array. We skip the first element, because all subsequent elements should be subtracted from the first element. Then we perform a [*reduction operation*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction), with as initial value the first element of the array, and we subtract the subsequent element from the previous result.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's a good idea to put initial value to `numArray[0]`, the code could be cleaner if it would be a separate variable.
Still, if you insist:

```
    @Test
    public void diffArray() {
        Integer [] numArray = {10,1,2,3};
        Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(numArray));
        Integer diff = v.stream().skip(1).reduce(numArray[0],(a,b)->a-b);
        org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat("", diff == 4);
    }
```